# Retrieve /feed or /tagged on facebook community pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, posts, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using FB graph API to fetch people's posts on community pages, such as [this](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hong-Kong-Baptist-Hospital/137392689617600)

I used the graph API explorer with [url](http://https:graph.facebook.com/v2.3/137392689617600/tagged%20but%20it%20displayed%20nothing.)

However, if I try the `/tagged` url with a non community page such as [this](http://https:graph.facebook.com/v2.3/ifdl.hk/tagged), I can retrieve people's posts on the page.

Do anyone know why /tagged only work in non community page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what do you mean with "Community pages" but this is a problem of permissions. Quoting the docs:

> /{page-id}/tagged shows the posts to this page. It will also show some
>   posts in which the page has been tagged. It will only show tagged
>   posts where the person who made the post have installed the same app.

Link to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

So probably you do not have permissions to see post for that particular page.

I hope it helps.